# Json Array Flattening with Jackson / Parsing Performance

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON like this below:
My aimed POJO is

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "teams": [{
                "name": "barca"
            },
            {
                "name": "real"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "teams": [{
                "name": "atletico"
            },
            {
                "name": "cz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My aimed POJO is

```
class Team
int id;
String name;
```

Meaning, for each "team" I want to create a new object. Like;

```
new Team(1,barca)
new Team(1,real)
new Team(2,null)
new Team(3,atletico)
...
```

Which I believe I did with custom deserializer like below:

```
            JsonNode rootArray = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
            for (JsonNode root : rootArray) {
                String id = root.get("id").toString();
                JsonNode teamsNodeArray = root.get("teams");
                if (teamsNodeArray != null) {
                    for (JsonNode teamNode: teamsNodeArray ) {
                        String nameString = teamNode.get("name").toString();
                        teamList.add(new Team(id, nameString));
                    }
                } else {
                    teamList.add(new Team(id, null));
                }
            }
```

Condidering I am getting 750k records... having 2 fors is I believe making the code way slower than it should be. It takes ~7min.

My question is, could you please enlighten me if there is any better way to do this?

PS: I have checked many stackoverflow threads for this, could not find anything that fits so far.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse the data yourself, use automatic de/serialization whenever possible.

Using jackson it could be as simple as:

```
MyData myData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(rawData, MyData.class);
```

For you specific example, we generate a really big instance (10M rows):

```
$ head big.json 
[{"id": 1593, "group": "6141", "teams": [{"id": 10502, "name": "10680"}, {"id": 16435, "name": "18351"}]}
,{"id": 28478, "group": "3142", "teams": [{"id": 30951, "name": "3839"}, {"id": 25310, "name": "19839"}]}
,{"id": 29810, "group": "8889", "teams": [{"id": 5586, "name": "8825"}, {"id": 27202, "name": "7335"}]}
...
$ wc -l big.json 
10000000 big.json
```

Then, define classes matching your data model (e.g.):

```
public static class Team {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

public static class Group {
    public int id;
    public String group;
    public List<Team> teams;
}
```

Now you can read directly the data by simply:

```
List<Group> xs = new ObjectMapper()
                   .readValue(
                       new File(".../big.json"),
                       new TypeReference<List<Group>>() {});
```

A complete code could be:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Group> xs = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("/home/josejuan/tmp/1/big.json"), new TypeReference<List<Group>>() {});

    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // test: add all group id
    long groupIds = xs.stream().mapToLong(x -> x.id).sum();

    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.printf("Group id sum := %d, Read time := %d mS, Sum time = %d mS%n", groupIds, t1 - t0, t2 - t1);
}
```

With output:

```
Group id sum := 163827035542, Read time := 10710 mS, Sum time = 74 mS
```

Only **11 seconds** to parse **10M rows**.

To check data and compare performance, we can read directly from disk:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print "$1\n" if /"id": ([0-9]+), "group/' big.json | time awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
163827035542
4.96user
```

Using **5 seconds** (the *Java* code is only half as slow).

The non-performance problem of processing the data can be solved in many ways depending on how you want to use the information. For example, grouping all the teams can be done:

```
List<Team> teams = xs.stream()
                     .flatMap(x -> x.teams.stream())
                     .collect(toList());

Map<Integer, Team> uniqTeams = xs.stream()
                                 .flatMap(x -> x.teams.stream())
                                 .collect(toMap(
                                      x -> x.id,
                                      x -> x,
                                      (a, b) -> a));
```

Comment: Hi... Thought about this, but this solution doesn't give me the "flattening" I want. I think If I wanted this way I could just use the annotations... My point is to create new instances from the inner array.

Comment: Hi @Bleach I can't quite understand the structure of your data (e.g. the `name` field does not appear in the `json`) nor how you need to aggregate it. In any case, once you have the data, it should not be difficult, as the 7 minute performance loss is caused by how you parse the `json` (not the loop).

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I made a typo in the source json. Now I edited it, and `name` is there. So what you're saying is that the performance loss is inevitable in this case?

Comment: Both problems performance ( _"Only 11 seconds to parse 10M rows."_ ) and transformation have been solved. Take your time to understand the answer and try to apply it to your case :)

Comment: I see... But sadly I cannot adopt this implementation... At least I don't know how to do it so without a creating wrapper object.

Comment: Very detailed answer.